# Custom Strikethrough CSS

Tags: html, css, text, overlay

I want to change the behaviour of the "del" HTML tag, such that it overlays a diagonal slash on each character.

This could be done with a bitmap graphic, a colour gradient, placing a "/" character over each previous character, or something else, but hopefully not using javascript.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the slash need to be placed in the same place on each character? Are you using a monospace font?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Sorry, I should have specified. I've been using a specially created character in unicode PUA - a slash, but with zero width spacing, and the placement one character-space to the left. So after every normal character, this gets pasted. It works, but it's very clunky.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @Milken: I've tried the background-image and repeating-linear-gradient methods - also suggested by Johnathan below. Having difficulty with the after:: method suggested by Hans. Also tried creating a modified font, replacing the bold-italic characters with struckthru regular chars. Works, but very inefficient.

Comment: @Kapitano Is there something that does not work with my methods?  As for the :after method, I don't see how it would possible to have one strike per character (without essentially using it as a combination with one of my methods).  I'm hoping Hans is working on an answer to better explain.

Comment: @Johnathan: Everything you suggest works, except that the graphic or gradient appears //behind// the text, and I want it in front. I'm happy for green text to be struck out by red slashs (for instance), but at the moment the text strikes out the striking.

Comment: @Kapitano I've been thinking about this, and it poses some difficulties with line-breaks, unless you are willing / able to put a `<del>` around each word.  Is that a possibility?

Comment: @Johnathan: Hmm. On one hand, it would be trivially easy with the RegEx macros I'm using to format the text. On the other...it's a lot of workaround for a minor effect. I'll keep working on your suggestions, but make other aspects of the project the priority.

Comment: @Johnathan, Milken, Hans: My eventual solution was to define a parallel font family, composed of the same characters, each with a diagonal line through, and instead of `<del>...</del>`, use `<span class="MyFont Strike">...</span>`. Perverse, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, this would be fairly easy to do with a monospace font.  The easiest would probably be with `background-image`.

Obviously, with CSS-only, there will be no way of distinguishing a space from any other character, so either they will be crossed out like the other letters, or you would have to put a `<del>` tag around each word.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

del {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/OBq3XE9.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 88%;
  background-position: left 26%;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}

.red del {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/GISo6rF.png);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  Test! Do <del>not ever think of</del> try this at home.  And <del>cross</del> <del>out</del> <del>individual</del> words like this.
</div>
<div class="red">
  Test! Do <del>not ever think of</del> try this at home.
</div>
```

You could also accomplish this with `background: repeating-linear-gradient`:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

del {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      -65deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 6px,
      #000 6px,
      #000 7px,
      transparent 7px,
      transparent 8px
    );
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
.red del {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      -65deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 6px,
      #f00 6px,
      #f00 7px,
      transparent 7px,
      transparent 8px
    );
}
```

```html
<div>
  Test! Do <del>not ever think of</del> try this at home.
</div>
<div class="red">
  Test! Do <del>not ever think of</del> try this at home.
</div>
```

Comment: This works, provided the text colour matches the background image. Unfortunately, I'm using several text colours.

Comment: If you want to place the slash on top, you can use a `::after` psuedo-element, and absolutely position if over the `del` tag with 100% width and height. (You'll need to relatively position the `del` tag to get the absolute to snap to it)

Comment: @Kapitano You could create multiple images to match the font colours you are using, see updated post.

Comment: I added another example as well how you could do it with `repeating-linear-gradient`.  This has the obvious advantage of supporting as many colours as you want without generating new images.